# Why /Applications Folder not opening in Finder but works in Terminal?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded to Yosemite, but I'm not sure if this is a Yosemite-related bug.

My application folder (/Applications) does not open in finder (see screenshots)
The spinner keep spinning in the bottom right corner.
Also, when I "Get Info", it keeps calculating the size and never completes.
Also, when I drag the Applications folder to the dock, nothing happens.

However, it works fine in Terminal:

```
$ cd /; ls -lh
drwxrwxr-x+ 129 root   admin   4.3K Oct 17 03:14 Applications
```

When I go inside the Applications folder (in terminal), I can list all the files in it.Oddly enough, most of them are greyed out, and it only says "total 8" when I have way more than 8 apps.

```
$ cd /Applications; ls -lh
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   wheel   136B Apr 23  2013 3Hub.app
drwxr-xr-x@  4 myusername  staff   136B May 20 13:02 Adium.app
drwxrwxr-x   5 root   admin   170B Feb  7  2013 Adobe
drwxrwxr-x@  7 root   admin   238B Feb 14  2013 Adobe Acrobat XI Pro
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root   admin    92B Feb 14  2013 Adobe Application Manager -> /Applications/Utilities/Adobe Application Manager/CCM/Utilities/AdobeCreativeCloudClient.app
drwxrwxr-x@  8 root   admin   272B Feb  7  2013 Adobe Bridge CS6
drwxr-xr-x@  3 myusername  staff   102B Jul 20  2012 Adobe Cleaner.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 myusername  staff   102B Dec 12  2012 Adobe Download Assistant.app
drwxrwxr-x@  6 root   admin   204B Feb  7  2013 Adobe Extension Manager CS6
drwxrwxr-x@ 13 root   admin   442B Feb  7  2013 Adobe Illustrator CS6
drwxrwxr-x@ 13 root   admin   442B Feb  7  2013 Adobe Photoshop CS6
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   wheel   102B Feb  7  2013 Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 4.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 myusername  admin   102B Oct 15  2012 Air Video Server.app
drwxr-x---@  5 myusername  staff   170B Dec 12  2013 Android Development Kit
drwxr-xr-x+  3 root   wheel   102B Jul 11 15:49 App Store.app
```

I can even open my apps in Terminal:

```
$ cd /Applications; open Notes.app
```

Mission Control works fine as well.

Does anyone know how I can see my Applications in Finder?
I've tried the usual Disk Utility (verify/repair permissions) and even reinstalled a fresh copy of Mac OSX Yosemite (using recovery).

Note: I did mess around with ~/Library/Preferences immediately after installing Yosemite because of the background flashing bug (I deleted some plists files to fix that bug).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

MacBook Pro (Retina, Mid 2012), OS X Yosemite (10.10), upgrade from latest mavericks

Comment: Perhaps a corrupt .DS_Store file in /Applications? Could try deleting it to see if the issue remains.

Comment: I've tried deleting it.

Comment: Is this limited to your user account?

Comment: @Scot nope, it's system wide.

Comment: I've seen the Finder grow so laggy - sometimes a forced restart (of Finder) helps.